# Registry Expiry Date

Tags: домен

Что значит параметр `Registry Expiry Date` для доменов в зоне `.com` в сравнении с параметрами `paid-till` и `free-date`? Я так понимаю, что `paid-till` - время, до которого оплачено, и с этого времени до `free-date` владелец еще может продлить домен. Правильно? А что означает `Registry Expiry Date`? Можно ли его продлить после этого срока и если да, то сколько времени по его истечении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементарно же гуглится: "дата окончания срока регистрации домена по данным Реестра". Продлится когда регистратор отправит/оплатит запрос на продление в реестр

Comment: Больше волнует вопрос, в течение какого времени можно продлить после этой даты.

Comment: Месяц, но лучше уточнить у регистратора. А, ну и домен будет недоступен

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.